# java.lang.AssertionError: null at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndex.createInstance

Tags: cassandra

ERROR 07:02:14,796  Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndex.createInstance(SecondaryIndex.java:347) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.addIndexedColumn(SecondaryIndexManager.java:283) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.(ColumnFamilyStore.java:390) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:527) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:498) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:335) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.(Keyspace.java:275) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:121) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:98) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:332) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:365) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:566) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:74) [dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndex.createInstance(SecondaryIndex.java:347)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.addIndexedColumn(SecondaryIndexManager.java:283)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.(ColumnFamilyStore.java:390)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:527)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:498)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:335)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.(Keyspace.java:275)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:121)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:98)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:332)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:365)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:566)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:74)
Exception encountered during startup: null
INFO  07:02:14,798  DSE shutting down...
INFO  07:02:14,798  All plugins are stopped.
ERROR 07:02:14,812  Exception in thread Thread[Daemon shutdown,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStateInternal(Gossiper.java:1419) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStates(Gossiper.java:1443) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationState(Gossiper.java:1433) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.18.1463.jar:2.1.18.1463]
    at com.datastax.bdp.gms.DseState.setBooleanApplicationState(DseState.java:447) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at com.datastax.bdp.gms.DseState.setActiveStatusSync(DseState.java:249) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preStop(DseDaemon.java:458) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.safeStop(DseDaemon.java:469) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon$1.run(DseDaemon.java:723) ~[dse-core-4.8.15.jar:4.8.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]

Comment: Please add at least 1-2 senteces with a question or describe your problem. Throwing uncommented exception messages at the community is ... ummm...

Answer (score 0):

DSE 4.7~dse 4.8 can have this issue with DSE solr
this can be caused by  index_options column having null value for a column that has DSE solr index enabled,
Index option should be set to

index_options='{"class_name":"com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex"}'

First we need to fix the up nodes by updating solr index column's index_options value like above . it should not be null.

Then copy schema_columns table content from good nodes to bad nodes and restart the node.

The issue does not allow dse solr to start, but with this fix,it should start correctly.